# Adding switch to thermostat to control remote fan

Tags: switch, thermostat, fans

A room at the end of my HVAC forced air is cold due to lack of air flow. I’d like to add a booster fan to help with airspeed and I’d like it to turn on/off based on the thermostat switch turning the zone on/off.  With smart plugs I’m trying to determine a way for the 24V thermostat switch to also turn on the booster fan wirelessly.  I’m thinking the 24V switch would be tapped off to a switch that controls a wireless on/off remote smart plug the fan is plugged into.  However I can’t find any 24V switched wireless connections.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is running some thermostat wire out to the booster fan location out of the question...?

Comment: Correct - The thermostat is about 40 feet and 3 rooms away and that would be a prohibitive undertaking

Comment: If code/safety permitted (I'm not sure, but *maybe*) could you run low voltage control wire (i.e., 24V from the thermostat circuits) through the duct work?

Comment: I actually have easy access to the duct.  It’s getting the duct to the thermostat that is the problem (which is why wireless is the only clean way to do it). I also can’t connect the location of the motor fan to the furnace but good thought

Comment: @MattT -- can you get from the fan location to the existing furnace/air-handler with the thermostat wire?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Too many kinks and bends in finished walls and opposite side of house down two floors

Comment: If you can made 2 thermistors measure the temperature or R difference detect warm air relative the wall temp not far away or baseboard  control a DC fan variable speed , that might work.

Answer (score 1):

There are sensor switches that are designed for inline boosters, something like that:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Suncourt-Ductstat-Plug-In-Thermostat-Temperature-Sensitive-Switch-DS100

There are also "register booster" fans with built-in thermostats, but those might be restricting more airflow than helping.

They are supposed to turn on and off when temperature changes (when furnace turns on/off).